# How to automate storage of regression estimates into separate matrices in R

Tags: r

I am trying to run a multiple imputation sensitivity analysis. I have provided a simulated data below to demonstrate my problem.

I have already run a multiple imputation model by imputing predicted data to missing values. The next step I wanted to do is to automate a sensitivity analysis where I add to the predicted outcome a multiple of the standard error of the model (sigma). I show my code below. I have six (excluding zero) sensitivity factors for my sensitivity imputation, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3. Each factor is multiplied by the standard error of the model residual and added to the predicted values. Here is the code I used to modify predicted values, `+ (delta) * summary(cc.m)$sigma` . You need to comment this out for the loop to work at this time.

My question: How can I automate the process so that I have a separate matrix for each of my sensitivity analyses so I have an efficient code. I am happy to clarify if this is not clear. I know I can do them separately or use an existing package. I don't want to take these steps. Below is my code. 
Thanks!

```
# Generating data
score <- rnorm(20, 0)            # my outcome variable
age <- rnorm(20, mean= 7.5)      # Age
gender <- rbinom(20, 1, 0.5)     # Gender
missing <- rbinom(20, 1, 0.3)    # zero is observed

# Simulated data
dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(score, age, gender, missing))

# Generating missing data for score, my outcome
dat$score[data$missing == 1] <- NA 

# Generating number of imputations, keeping it small for now
B <- 10

# Generating sensitivity parameter
delta <- seq(-3,3,1)

# Generating empty matrix to store beta estimates
beta.mat <- matrix(NA, nrow = B, ncol = 3)

# Running an imputation loop
for (j in 1:B) {

  # complete cases model
  cc.m <- lm(score ~ age + gender, data = dat, subset=dat$missing==0)

  ### Generating predicted values + I add a sensitivity paramter, delta.
  dat$score.hat <- predict(cc.m, newdat <- dat) + (delta) * summary(cc.m)$sigma    # Here I am modifying the predicted values by a sensitivity parameter.

  # Replacing predicted values by actual values for those that are observed
  dat$score.hat[dat$missing==0] <- dat$score[dat$missing==0]

  # Running the imputed model
  imp.m <- lm(score.hat ~ age + gender, data = dat)

  # Saving estimates in a matrix, but at this time this only saves values for only one of the sensitivity parameters.
  beta.mat[j,] <- c(summary(imp.m)$coef[,1])
}
```

Comment: Use `library(Amelia)`. That is to say that I don't understand why, statistically speaking, you are doing imputations in the manner shown above.

Comment: @Alex Thanks, but I don't want to use a package! I want to know how to do this from the ground up.

Comment: @Alex There are many ways to approach the sensitivity analysis. I am using the standard error of the residuals to alter predicted values of cases that have missing values - for now.

Comment: From a statistical perspective: Why are you doing imputations via `lm`? And why is the 'sensitivity' proportional to the MLE of the sd random error?

Comment: There are different recommendations on how to go about the sensitivity value. E.g. One is using the s.d. of the complete cases model, another is the s.d. of the outcome. In my actual data, the two values seem close, so I am OK with it at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options:

Store your output in a list:

```
beta.mat <- list()

for (j in 1:B) {
  ...
  beta.mat[[j]] <- summary(imp.m)$coef
}
```

Use `assign()`:

```
for (j in 1:B) {
  ...
  assign(paste0("beta.mat",j),summary(imp.m)$coef)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sam Dickenson. I tried using those, no luck unfortunately. Note that I am interested in creating a separate matrix to store estimations from each of the delta modifiers. So I think there needs to be a way to loop through the different delta values, i.e, I need seven separate matrices.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want.  Maybe if you provided some sample output?

Comment: And what's in `beta.mat3`?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out finally. The trick is to save the separate matrices from each sensitivity simulation into an array. So we will have a [100,3,7] array. I believe this is memory efficient. But I am happy to hear what people think. I need to run this 10,000 times on 15 variables on a totally different data set. I show my code below.

```
# Generating data
score <- rnorm(20, 0)            # My outcome variable
age <- rnorm(20, mean= 7.5)      # Age
gender <- rbinom(20, 1, 0.5)     # Gender
missing <- rbinom(20, 1, 0.3)    # Zero is observed

# Simulated data
dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(score, age, gender, missing))

# Generating missing data for score, my outcome
dat$score[data$missing == 1] <- NA 

# Generating number of imputations
B <- 100

# Generating sensitivity parameter
delta <- seq(-3,3,1)

# Generating empty matrix to store beta estimates
beta.arr <- array(c(matrix(NA, nrow = B, ncol = 3)), c(B, 3, length(delta)) )

# Running an imputation loop
for (j in 1:B) {  

# Running a sensitivity loop  
for (i in 1: length(delta)) { 

  # Complete cases model
  cc.m <- lm(score ~ age + gender, data = dat, subset=dat$missing==0)

  # Generating predicted values + I add a delta sensitivity paramter
  dat$score.hat <- predict(cc.m, newdat <- dat) + (delta[i]) * summary(cc.m)$sigma

  # Replacing predicted values by actual observations
  dat$score.hat[dat$missing==0] <- dat$score[dat$missing==0]

  # Running the imputed model
  imp.m <- lm(score.hat ~ age + gender, data = dat)

  # Saving estimates in a matrix
  beta.arr[j, ,i ] <- c(summary(imp.m)$coef[,1])
}
}

# Then estimation becomes easier
# Here I save the summary of sensitivity estimates in an array.
est.mat <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(delta), ncol=3)
for(i in 1:length(delta)) {
est.mat[i,] <- apply(beta.arr[, , i], 2, mean)
}

# snapshot of summary estimates matrix for each variable, and the intercept
head(est.mat)
```